# What callback URI should i mention on creating a Twitter Application using its API? What does it actually mean?

Tags: android, twitter, callback

I am creating an Mobile application using API provided by the twitter for developers. What callback URI should i mention on creating a Twitter Application  using its API? What does it actually mean?
https://apps.twitter.com/app/new

[Error image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kzs2.png)
[Error image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGfb5.png)

Comment: You might want to add more details to your post for others to be able to help out better.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide any url you mean to use where twitter can redirect user to on successful authentication. This can be overridden by callback_url parameter during authentication.

I have used my homepage as callback_url in the app settings and it has worked for me well. I redirect my user to another page on authentication by overriding the callback_url as suggested above.